# sencha touch android app not working on android 4 (D/chromium( 3938): Unknown chromium error: -6)

Tags: android, extjs, cordova, sencha-touch

i have build a android app with sencha 2.3 ,cmd 4 and phonegap 3. it is working fine in android 2.x devices but not able to make jsonp calls in android 4.x devices.

adb logcat show some D/chromium( 3938): Unknown chromium error: -6

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHk8Q.jpg

```
E/Web Console( 4232): Uncaught ReferenceError: Ext is not defined at file:///and
roid_asset/www/index.html:7
I/ActivityManager(  694): Displayed rd.yadav.riteyouth/.riteyouth: +1s427ms
I/Web Console( 4232): Could not find cordova.js script tag. Plugin loading may f
ail. at file:///android_asset/www/phonegap.js:1511
E/Genymotion(  694): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_pat
h/present'
D/chromium( 4232): Unknown chromium error: -6
D/chromium( 4232): Unknown chromium error: -6
I/Web Console( 4232): this is a store at file:///android_asset/www/app.js:1
D/chromium( 4232): Unknown chromium error: 0
D/chromium( 4232): Unknown chromium error: -6
E/Genymotion(  694): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_pat
h/present'
```

I also try to add

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    disableCaching: false
});

Ext.Ajax.setDisableCaching(false);
```

these lines in index.html but then this error is generated:

```
E/Web Console( 4232): Uncaught ReferenceError: Ext is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:7
```

Comment: Is the app packaged with Sencha CMD?

Comment: no, it is packeged with phonegap

Answer (score 0):

my problem is solve after whitelisting the domain.
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide